# Get JSON values from file to js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json file that holds data in this form:

```
{
  "UserEmail": "email@domain.com",
  "UserAvatar": "url",
  "Username": "Name",
  "Contacts": [
    "email2@domain.com",
    "emai3l@domain.com"
  ],
  "MyFriends": [
    "",
    ""
  ],
  "MyEnemies": [
    "",
    ""
  ],
  "FriendsAvatar": {
    "email2@domain.com": "url2",
    "email3@domain.com": "url3"
  }
}
```

I want to pass the data to js array so when I need a value to call the appropriate key. For `array_json['UserEmail']` I'll get `email@domain.com` as a result and for `array_json['Contacts']` another array with contact infos.

I search the past question here, but whenever I tried to use `$.getJSON()` JQuery function I get errors.

Here is what I think:

```
var obj = [];
  $.ajax({
    url: "json/HV.json",
    success: function (data) {
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(obj);
        }
    });
```

Comment: post jQuery function here. so we can help you

Comment: FYI. what you are talking about is an Object in js. You can indeed get values between brackets but in your case array_json['UserDetails'] is the same as array_json.UserDetails

Comment: @MathijsSegers ok I post it but it's ridiculous code I think :(

Comment: I believe you don't need to use JSON.parse, data is already an object at that point, try alert JSON.stringify(data); If you see your contents, then data is all you need.

Comment: okay okay it worked! What I suppose to do with my question now? @MathijsSegers

Comment: @GeorgeGkas just post your code and explain how you solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to use parse function. It can be accessed as below

```
 $.ajax({
   url: "json/HV.json",
   success: function (data) {
      alert(data.UserEmail);
   }
 });
```

See it is working in this snippet

```js
var data = {
  "UserEmail": "email@domain.com",
  "UserAvatar": "url",
  "Username": "Name",
  "Contacts": [
    "email2@domain.com",
    "emai3l@domain.com"
  ],
  "MyFriends": [
    "",
    ""
  ],
  "MyEnemies": [
    "",
    ""
  ],
  "FriendsAvatar": {
    "email2@domain.com": "url2",
    "email3@domain.com": "url3"
  }
}

alert(data.UserEmail)
```

Comment: yeap I figure it out lately. Anyway this is the answer I would posted so ,,, take credits!